# TexDraw not working

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm in the process of creating a beach scene, so, in order to do that I modeled some palms, but for some reason I can't seem to paint the texture.

I've created an image, UV unwrapped it and made a node for the texture, I'm using Cycles render.

If I say TexDraw doesn't work I mean, if I click the UV Map/Object in *Paint Mode* nothing happens, no texture appears.

The *Fill* and *Mask* tool seem to be working for some reason.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever get it resolved?

Answer (score 3):

Have you by any chance added a blank texture under the "Texture" section of the Tools tab?

If you do this, you won't be able to paint anything . . . because it is trying to paint with your (blank) texture.

The way to fix this is to delete the texture from the brush.

[image: blank texture messing up texture paint]

Personally I think this is a pretty confusing aspect of the UI . . .